# SonataAdmin - Custom form template for each form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm having problems with [Sonata Admin Bundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/index.html). What I would like to do is:

Add some text before some labels in my form. Like for example:

> The resolution of your image must be ..x.. .

For example I have a form like this:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
     $formMapper
         ->add('locale', 'choice', array(
             'choices'   => array('nl' => 'NL', 'en' => 'EN'),
             'required'  => true,
         ))
         ->add('pageid.tag', 'text', array('label' => 'Tag'))
         ->add('description', 'text', array('label' => 'Beschrijving'))
         ->add('content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Tekst', 'attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor')))
         ->add('files', 'file', array('required' => false, 'multiple' => true))
    ;
}
```

Now I would like to add some text before my files input field.

What I've done now is:

- Add this to my config.yml (overload the templates/form configuration option):

  ```
  sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
      # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
      entity_manager: ~

      templates:
          form:
              - MurisBundle:PageAdmin:form_admin_fields.html.twig
  ```

But this will be used for every form, can't I set specific form templates for specific forms?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify form template in your admin class overriding getFormTheme method.
Add this code to your admin class.

```
public function getFormTheme()
{
     return array_merge(
         parent::getFormTheme(),
         array('MurisBundle:PageAdmin:form_admin_fields.html.twig')
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getPictureUrlFull().'" alt="'.$campaign->getPicture().'" style="margin-top:10px;" />Use "help"

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
     $formMapper
         ->add('locale', 'choice', array(
             'choices'   => array('nl' => 'NL', 'en' => 'EN'),
             'required'  => true,
             'help'      => '<img src="'.$entity->getPictureUrlFull().'" alt="'.$entity->getPicture().'" />'               
         ))

)
```

Comment: I think that help text is actually rendered after field, not before